# C++ Input and Output problems

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, distance

My problem is that when i compile and run the program, the hours doesnt have "hours" listing 1,2,3 as the loop continues and also the loop calculation is the same for each line.

this is what the program looks like 
http://postimg.org/image/htk194eah/

the calculation is wrong and the hours is suppose to say 1,2...5

I would like it to look something like this
http://postimg.org/image/pnkvab1j1/

this is what i have so far:

```
int main()
{
    // Variables 
    int speed; 
    int time; 
    int distance; 

    // Obtain the speed


    cout << "Please input the speed of the vehicle  " ;
        cin >> speed;

  while(speed < 0) // while statement  
  {
   cout << "Please refrain from using a negative number   ";
        cin >> speed;
  }
     cout << "Please enter the time, represented in hours, travelled" <<endl;
     cin >> time;

   // Obtain the time
       while(speed < 1) 
  {
       cout<< "Please use a number greater than 1 " <<endl;
       cin >> time;
  }  

    // Calculation
    distance = speed * time;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Hour(s) " << "\t" << "Distance Travelled" << endl;
    cout << "____________________________________________" << endl;

    // "for" Loop statement
    for(int count =1; count <= time; count++)
  {
        cout << " " << "\t\t" << speed*time << endl;

  }



system ("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: C != C++. In general you should not cross tag as the languages can be very different.

Comment: `while(speed < 0) // while statement` great comment :)

Comment: // Obtain the time
       while(speed < 1)  This is probably wrong

Comment: I have great faith in your debugging skills, so use a debugger.  Edit your question with the line number that is causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print in your for loop, speed = 20 and time = 5 always, so it always prints 100 (in the example you give).

You want to be printing speed*count (in this case).

Again you print "" for the hours, which is an empty string, you want to be printing count.

```
cout << count << "\t\t" << speed*count << endl;
```

Comment: However how do i make the hours say 1,2,3...5?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct program. Your program was very good. But you have a very small mistake.

```
#include<iostream.h>
    main()
    {
        // Variables 
        int speed; 
        int time; 
        int distance; 

        // Obtain the speed


        cout << "Please input the speed of the vehicle  " ;
        cin >> speed;

      while(speed < 0) // while statement  
      {
       cout << "Please refrain from using a negative number   ";
            cin >> speed;
      }
      cout << "Please enter the time, represented in hours, travelled ";
      cin >> time;

       // Obtain the time
           while(speed < 1) 
      {
           cout<< "Please use a number greater than 1 ";
           cin >> time;
      }  

        // Calculation


        cout << endl;
        cout << "Hour(s) " << "\t" << "Distance Travelled" << endl;
        cout << "____________________________________________" << endl;

        // "for" Loop statement
        for(int count =1; count <= time; count++)
      {
            cout << count << "\t\t" << speed * count << endl;

      }



    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
    }
```